# Remove default params from one get axios request (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

what's up?
My problem is that when using a service create using `axios.create` with default params that doesn't use that params, the return is wrong, but, when the params is not send, the return is correctly, so i need to remove the params from some calls.

I created a service using `axios.create` that make the call using a complementary url, as below:

**api.ts**

```
export const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: "API_URL",
  timeout: 3000,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${SOME_ENV_TOKEN}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  },
  params: {
    keys: `${SOME_ENV_KEY}`,
  },
});
```

In my hooks, that service is used to fetch the data passing the complementary url, as bellow:

**useFetchUsers.ts**

```
const fetchUsers: IUsers = await service
      .get<Promise<IUsers>>(`/users/`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      });
```

However, some calls in one or two hook don't use the params to return the correct values, when the params is passed and not needed, the return from api is wrong.

What i need is to remove the params in some calls to get the correct values.

I already tried interceptors, but the params is remove from all api calls.

I tried to pass a empty object, but the params is used in the same way:

**useFetchUsers.ts**

```
const fetchUsers: IUsers = await service
      .get<Promise<IUsers>>(`/users/`, {})
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      });
```

And I also tried to pass an empty params (assign empty string or null), but the params is send as a null, that return a wrong values from api.

**useFetchUsers.ts**

```
const fetchUsers: IUsers= await service
      .get<Promise<IUsers>>(`/users/`, {params: {})
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      });
```

So, there's a way to remove the default params from axios call in a selected hook using this method?

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: so do you mean you want to clear `params` you've specified by default for `axios` instance(`service` variable)?

Comment: Yes, i don't want to send with the request, setting blank/null or leaving the object empty won't work. I want to clean or send nothing without creating new services without the params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you are using buggy old version of `axios`(like [0.19.0 was](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2190)) params for request are merged with default params in instance, not overwrite.

And also since `undefined` values are removed from `params` plus

> The specified config will be merged with the instance config.

then

```
const fetchUsers: IUsers= await service
  .get<Promise<IUsers>>(`/users/`, { params: { keys: undefined } })
  .then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  });
```

should work fine. At least it works this way to me with 1.2.1

Comment: Setting as undefined worked like a charm, i tried null or empty but forget to try undefined think that will work like null/empty, but it's not. Thanks for the whole explication.